# PHP equivalent of ASP.NET SqlDataSource

Tags: php, asp.net, gridview, sqldatasource

Last night I was doing a GridView combined with SqlDataSource in Visual Studio for my school project. Usualy I use PHP for web development, but that combination is really powerful, so I would like to know if there exists a PHP class that would implement the same idea as is SqlDataSource + GridView in ASP.NET?

Comment: Looks like a duplicate for ... http://stackoverflow.com/a/14468986/385377

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You might want to look at something like PhpGrid:

http://phpgrid.com/example/example-1-a-basic-php-datagrid-2/

```
$dg = new C_DataGrid("SELECT * FROM orders", "orderNumber", "orders");
$dg -> display();
```